# Uploading a JSON file with the same name to a PHP server takes effect after too much time

Tags: php, android

I have some android users who need a `JSON` file to be downloaded from a `PHP` server
Whenever the `JSON` file needs any modification, I download it, modify the items and upload the file again for further use by the users

If the name of the modified file which is supposed to be uploaded is the same previous name, there is a problem and the problem is the server is sensitive to some file types
You upload some files successfully but when the users download the files, yet the old files are downloaded as if there is no new file uploaded

For example if the file type is `JSON` type, the problem exists but if it is `PHP` type there is no problem
In fact it will take some time (the time is too much) for `JSON` type to be ready for download but `PHP` file is instantly ready for download
I called the server administrator and he said it's natural and `HTML` files have the same problem too
He said if I pay more money I can by virtual server which does not have that problem

Anyway I decided to rename the file each time I upload it to solve the problem

The process is as following:
1 - An `http` request is sent to the `PHP` code to identify the last uploaded file name
2 - `PHP` code searches the folder which contains the JSON file
3 - The name of the last uploaded file is identified and sent back to the client

Now that the file name is identified the file is downloadable and if need be the new file name for upload is identified too (Cause just 1 number is added to the previous number and then the file is uploaded)

The problem of such an process is speed of upload and download
Since 2 actions is necessary for each upload or download
1 - Identification of last uploaded file name
2 - Upload or download

Any suggestion?
Thanks

edit:
The code for download the JSON:

```
public class JSONHttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = JSONHttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public JSONHttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);//this is in milliseconds
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);//this is in milliseconds
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // make GET request to the given URL
            //conn.connect();

            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
            Log.e(TAG, "2222222222222222222222222" + response);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The code requested in comments for intentionally manipulating the JSON file for download test:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("j000000033w.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - reqUrl is the URL of the JSON file in the server ok ?

For a test that is ok.

But for what you really want not.

As then you would use a php script that would echo the file.